# Count(*) return 1 or zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

In one of the usecase I need a query which should return **1** based on condition also if not match it should return **0**

In Descpriont column if the 'SAP' count is exactly 1 then the query should return 1 else it should return 0

Note : There might be a chance that SAP could be present any number of times in Description column.

Could someone help me out here !!

Thanks.

I tried below query :

**SELECT 1 from TableName where Description ='SAP' having count(*)>1**

It is returning **1** but not return **0** if the count is more than 1 or no match found.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not clear and there is no data representing before and after states. Please make it more clear what is your problem ? Where is the code that is the problem ? What does it return and what do you expecti it to return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN` to decide whether to show 0 or 1.

```
select case when count(*) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as sap_count_is_1
from mytable
where description = 'SAP';
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select 
case when sum(case when description='SAP' then 1 else 0 end)=1 then 1 else 0 end from table_name
```